# What is the difference between the PHP directive local and global value?

Tags: php, memory-management, execution

Whats is the difference between the PHP directive local and global value, for example my local directive `max_execution_time` has the local value set to `600` and global value is `30` and still my site show the memory issues. 
May i need to increase the global value to resolve the memory issue i amd facing ?

Comment: The local definition should override the global. How and where are you setting this? What does `phpinfo()` tell you is the current value?

Comment: AFAIK execution time has nothing to do with memory issues

Comment: And `max_execution_time` doesn't help with memory issues..

Comment: @MagnusEriksson for phpinfo() showing 600 for local and 30 for global

Comment: Site is showing the maximum limit reached and gateway timeout errors. then which configuration i have to check ?

Comment: Maximum limit reached and gateway timeout? That sounds more like it's your web server that have hit its limit.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson do you have any idea which configurations of the server to change or i contact to my hoisting providers to resolve this issue ?

Comment: What server are you using? Do you have a lot of traffic? Either way, I would contact the hosting provider. They will be able to investigate why this happens. I can only guess (and I'm not an expert when it comes to server configurations).